# Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'like' - POWERSHELL

Tags: powershell

What is wrong with this code?
I need to check if the line has "2103Training" and "2103\sac" string in it and not modify the line if it does

```
  Get-ChildItem "E:\online\*" -Include *.levl1,*.levl2,*.levl3 -File | 
 ForEach-Object{
  $Path = $_.FullName
  $fileName="$Path.MODIFIED"
  $FileOriginal = Get-Content $Path
  $FileModified = @() 
 Foreach ($Line in $FileOriginal) {
 if ( (!$Line.like($OLDPRODVERSION+"Training")) -or (!$Line.like("$OLD_VER\sac\*.* , e:\$OLD_VER\sac"))    ) 
 {
    $FileModified = $Line.Replace( "$OLD_VER","NEW_VER") 
   }
 else 
  {
   $FileModified += $Line
  }
}
Set-Content -Path $filename -value $FileModified
Copy-Item -Path $fileName -Destination $Path 
Remove-Item -Path $fileName -Force
```

}

I am getting the below error

```
   Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'like'.
```

Comment: `like` is a comparison operator not a method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: that is caused by `if ( (!$Line.like($O` ... there is NO `.Like()` method for strings ... and you seem to have a string  in that $Var at that point. [*grin*] ///// here is one way to see the methods listed ... >>> `[string] | Get-Member -MemberType Methods` <<<

Comment: What @SantiagoSquarzon said. Replace `!$Line.like($OLDPRODVERSION+"Training")` with `$Line -notlike "${OLDPRODVERSION}Training"`